# How do you read errors into a pipe in c?

Tags: c, pipe, fork

How do you read `stderr` when using `execvp`, running a command that outputs and error in the terminal using this script will result in an empty buffer (no text)

```
int cmd(char * const *cmd, char * output)
{
    int pipefds[2], r, status, x;  
    pid_t pid;

    if (pipe(pipefds) == -1){
        return -1;
    }
    if ( (pid = fork()) == -1){
        return -1;
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        dup2(pipefds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(pipefds[0]);
        close(pipefds[1]);
        execvp(cmd[0] , cmd);
    }
    else
    {
        close(pipefds[1]);
        x = read(pipefds[0], output, 16384);
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

all the resources that I found online do not seem to mention where/how to pipe the error into the buffer, what are the three file descriptors in `pipefds` one for `stdin` another for `stdout` what about the last one `stderr`?

Comment: Note that `pipefds` just has two file descriptors and it can't have three because the array is defined to have two elements.  You can learn more about its contents by reading the man page for the `pipe` system call which populates the array:  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling `execvp`, set it up so that file descriptor `STDERR_FILENO` (i.e. `2`) goes to the pipe.

You can simply dup it an extra time, e.g.:

```
dup2(pipefds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(pipefds[1], STDERR_FILENO);
```

now both file descriptors 1 (stdout) and 2 (stderr) point to the same pipe.

Comment: for some reason I am not getting any error output from the code

Comment: @loaded_dypper error output should be going into the pipe. Are you sure your program reads ***ALL*** of the output from the pipe?

Comment: i believe so yes the buffer size is large enough and i the same syntax as you and I changed the command to `/bin/ifconfig` which is not found in that path and should display an error

Comment: @loaded_dypper I don't think your program reads ***ALL*** of the output from the pipe. Notice that `read` returns as soon as even one byte is ready

Comment: I used a while loop with `malloc` and `realloc` but i still get the same result it reads the first 8 bytes then returns

Comment: @loaded_dypper how does your loop know when to stop?

Comment: like so `while ( (x = read(pipefds[0], tmp, 1024)) > 0)`

Comment: You could compile a new program that only prints `hello world` to stderr and see if you can read that.

Comment: @infinitezero yes this works fine but when using a `/nobinary` does not show anything while it should show `zsh: no such file or directory: /nobinary`

Comment: @loaded_dypper why would it show that, that message comes from zsh and you are not running zsh